# Python get the string in quotes

Tags: python, string, extract, quotes

Hello I have file data as specified below

```
ID=3161
Author=Mark 
Context= "eric
speaking 
to 
mark 
about 
goldeninfo"
tag = "dramatic"
type = novel
```

I would like to extract any information represented in quotes. I was able to extract the information specifyed in quotes for tag but I'm not able to get the information for content using the below regex.

I would like to extract value if  the specified in quotes else I would like to extract the value not in quotes. Open for suggestions.

```
quoted = re.compile('"[^"].*"')
if value in quoted.findall(string): 
  extract it 


elif value not in quoted.findall(string):
   #extract it
```

Thanks

```
Output expected : 
Context= "eric speaking to mark about goldeninfo"
tag = "dramatic"
```

Comment: your `elif` is an `else`.

Comment: Your regex pattern means : a quote ``"`` , one character consisting in any character except a quote (that's ``[^"]``) , succession of any characters (except dots if re.DOTALL isn't activated) as far as possible , the last character must be a quote. I guess it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
>>> match = re.findall('"(.*?)"', string, re.DOTALL)
>>> ' '.join(match[0].split('\n'))
'eric speaking  to  mark  about  goldeninfo' 
>>>
>>> match[1]
'dramatic'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your regex means *"a character other than `"` followed by any number of any character"*, and not (as I suppose you intended) *"any number of characters other than `"`"*

Also note that `[^"]` includes newlines, whereas `.` does not.

Instead, try `'"[^"]*"'`.

```
>>> print re.findall('"[^"]*"', string)
['"eric\nspeaking \nto \nmark \nabout \ngoldeninfo"', '"dramatic"']
```